# startActivity creates a new Activity instead of bring to front (flag set)

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock, fragment

Imagine two activities A and B.

1. A starts an activity B (that will be on the top of the backstack)
2. creates a pending intent and attaches it to notification that permits to go back to the new activity B. The flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT is set in order to have JUST ONE ACTIVITY B (the one we created in step 1)
3. I go out of the app, I open my notification bar and I click my notification. I expect that I go back to the activity B create in step 1. Well.. it CREATES A NEW ACTIVITY B, putting it on the top of the backstack. What!? I don't understand this behavior!

Now some more details about this that could matter (do I detect a bug smell?):

- The step 1 and 2 are performed in a Fragment that activity A has.
- I use the support v4 library and the activity is an extension of SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
//Activity B creates and showed
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
getActivity().startActivity(i);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Prova2.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
notificationIntent.putExtra("test", "hi I'm a test");

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
String n = MyApplication.getAppContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(n);

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "test", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "testtitle", "texttest",
                    contentIntent);
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

nm.notify(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your `Flag` set on `notificationIntent` instead of `Intent` for `ActivityB`. Change this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
 getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

to

```
   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
   getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

[Google I/O Navigation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwGHJJYBs0Q) this link is very helpful in understanding how the stack works

Comment: it seems not to work. Both of the intents now have REORDER_TO_FRONT but the weird behavior keeps going the same.

Comment: What do you mean that it starts a new Activity B? Is there two Activity B's on the stack so if you press back it will take you to a new Activity B? Depending on how you leave the app or if Android needs to reclaim memory, some data may not be saved

Comment: Am I maybe wrong to say that it's on the top of the backstack? I thought abou that just because if I press the "back" button I see another activity B. Are they maybe two different backstacks?

Comment: Try using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` instead. There can be multiple tasks on the stack which I believes happen when you launch from notification. I will post a link in a moment that will help you understand better

Comment: When A creates the notification and the first activity B (through startActivity) I have just one activity B (the one shown after these two operations). In fact, if I click the back button, I go back to the previous activity of the stack (activity A).
Now.. consider I'm on the activity B. I press the home button, I open the notifications bar and I select my notification. Now I'm back to my app, but with a shiny new activity B, whereas the first activiy B created before is just under this new B.

Comment: I've tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and.. nothing new happens! Your link will be more than welcome though :)

Comment: I've posted the link with my answer. Those videos are very helpful. I will try to look at it some more in a bit

Comment: Thanks for the video anyway. It does not fix the issue, but at least it wiped up my backstack knowledge. So that I can say now that what I wrote in my app makes sense and I don't get what I expect from it.

Comment: I've maybe found out the reason (but it still remains quite weird). My actual intent (let's call it A1) is used to call an activity that is already on the TOP. 
So, just to make a try I used in my intent an reference to an activity (A2) that is already created, but not on the top.
Now let's imagine to use the pendingintent (and the intent). A2 is brought to the top. From A2, that is now on the top, I call a startactivity to float back my previous activity on the top (A1). And everything works smoothly!
It's of course a workaround and I still wonder why it works like that.

Comment: That's great if it is working for you now. But to be honest, its a little hard for me to understand exactly how you are doing it without seeing more of it so I can't really tell you why

Comment: no worries! The project is quite big, so I tried to put it simple here . I still think that some of the libraries I used messed the app's stack system  manager up.
Thank you so much for your support anyway!